# Find sub-array with given sum sub array should be continuous

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

**Find sub-array with given sum sub array should be continuous.**
This question is from GeeksForGeeks. [enter link description here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-subarray-with-given-sum/)

```
int subArraySum(int arr[], int n, int sum)
{
    /* Initialize curr_sum as value of first element
       and starting point as 0 */
    int curr_sum = arr[0], start = 0, i;

    /* Add elements one by one to curr_sum and if the curr_sum exceeds the
       sum, then remove starting element */
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        // If curr_sum exceeds the sum, then remove the starting elements
        while (curr_sum > sum && start < i-1) // Check This
        {
            curr_sum = curr_sum - arr[start];
            start++;
        }

        // If curr_sum becomes equal to sum, then return true
        if (curr_sum == sum)
        {
            printf ("Sum found between indexes %d and %d", start, i-1);
            return 1;
        }

        // Add this element to curr_sum
        if (i < n)
          curr_sum = curr_sum + arr[i];
    }

    // If we reach here, then no subarray
    printf("No subarray found");
    return 0;
}
```

In this we are using condition **while (curr_sum > sum && start < i-1)**. I don't think we need comparing start with i-1. We are able to do this **only while (curr_sum > sum)**. Please reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right in a way, but check problem definition closer:

- Input: arr[] = {1, 4}, sum = 0
- Output: No subarray found

With proposed modification, algorithm would behave differently.